# Why use the :"string val" notation to declare a symbol

Tags: ruby, syntax, literals

`:"String Val"` creates a symbol that stores `"String Val"`. `:"Hello Kitty".class` returns `Symbol`. I imagine this is to create a symbol that has spaces. I can't think of any reasons why this would be useful except methods that force require symbols.

Is there any other reason to use this?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "methods that force require symbols".

Comment: _"why this would be useful"_ – having this syntax or being able to have unusual symbol names?

Comment: @sawa def abc(sym) throw Exception.new("Only symbols allowed") unless sym.class == Symbol end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important reason for that is to utilize string interpolation, which allows symbols to be dynamically generated.

```
5.times.map{ |x| :"symbol_#{x}" }
=> [:symbol_0, :symbol_1, :symbol_2, :symbol_3, :symbol_4]
```

Comment: You are right, but I think it is more common to use `String#to_sym` for such cases.

Comment: Probably. Ruby creators apparently considered this feature important. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html section Symbols

Answer (score 2):

It's not just spaces, it's any gibberish that would otherwise be considered something that should be interpreted. Like

```
:"zoo@-55**12 +foo(3, baz)[7] - ❤️"
```

Quotes mean *"use as is"*. Which makes them intuitive as literal syntax for strings, but you can see that there are other uses.

---

But saying *"just"* methods that require symbols instead of strings is a bit misleading. Despite what Rails tries to make you believe, symbols and strings are very different and should be treated differently. Symbols are usually used as a sort of magical constants, while strings are regular values.

It's like saying why do we need `String#to_i`. Is it just for methods that treat `42` and `"42"` differently?

---

As for why there is literal syntax for it - just convenience (like any other syntax sugar). Consider:

```
{
  something_something:            1,
  something_completely_different: 2,
  'yet something else':           3,
}
```

It would be unfortunate if we had to write:

```
{
  :something_something            => 1,
  :something_completely_different => 2,
  'yet something else'.to_sym     => 3,
}
```

Or

```
{
  something_something:            1,
  something_completely_different: 2,
  'yet something else'.to_sym =>  3,
}
```

Comment: We do have `String#to_sym`. I think what the OP really wanted to ask is when to use `:"..."` instead of `to_sym`.

Comment: @sawa I got a different impression by this sentence *"I can't think of any reasons why this would be useful except methods that force require symbols."*. But as with any other syntax sugar - because it's more convenient and concise.

Comment: Your added part messes up your otherwise correct answer. The Ruby 1.9 hash syntax has no direct relation to the symbol literal syntax in issue here. Either can exist without the other.

Comment: @sawa, yep, I agree they are separate. It would be weird if we had the hash syntax, but not the symbol literal syntax though.

Comment: He actually did have some time with the hash syntax but not the symbol literal.

Answer (score 2):

There is already `String#to_sym`. Given this fact, it may seem that `:"..."` is a syntax sugar that can always be replaced by `String#to_sym`. But that is actually not the case. Besides for the convenience of the programmer, there has to be a notation `:"..."` irrespective of the existence of `String#to_sym`, at least for inspection. In this example,

```
"foo bar".to_sym
# => :"foo bar"
```

the inspection form cannot be `"foo bar".to_sym`, which expresses application of a method to a string, because the same object can be obtained in many other ways, and that is just one way to create such object. There has to be a unique way to express such symbol, which is `:"foo bar"`.

Once we have such expression for inspection, it is natural that that expression can also be used as a symbol literal.

Comment: While it's intuitive, isn't this like saying because `Object.new` has to be visualised somehow, `#<Object:0x007fcb2486d700>` should also be a literal syntax for creating said object.

Comment: @ndn What would `#<Object:0x007fcb2486d700>` mean?

Comment: The inspection form could just be `:foo bar`. The fact that it resembles a valid literal is just another convenience.

Comment: @Stefan Right. It is just another convenience, but that is a strong motivation for having such notation. And I do not think `:foo bar`in inspection would be clear enough.

Comment: @sawa, literal syntax for creating an instance of `Object` on that address perhaps. (: My point was that it's not necessary to have the same literal syntax for creating stuff as for inspection.

Comment: Although not literals, but `Float::NAN` and `Float::INFINITY` are counter-examples – they print as `NaN` and `Infinity`.

Comment: I do understand its much more convinient for inspection. I think the string interpolation answer makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Here is another use case:

```
:3
# => syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END

:"3"
# => :"3"
```